# Obsolete AstronomicalData - how to convert to PlanetData

Tags: curated-data, astronomy

As of *Mathematica* version 10, `AstronomicalData` is obsolete, deprecated in favor of `PlanetData`, `CometData`, `MinorPlanetData`, `PlanetaryMoonData`, `ExoplanetData`, `StarData`, `GalaxyData`, `NebulaData`, `PulsarData`, and friends. (It still works, but who knows how long for?) There are also many other changes, such as units/quantities, and DateObjects, which I'm struggling with for the first time.

How would I update code like this:

```
Table[AstronomicalData["Jupiter", {"Declination", x}], 
   {x, DayRange[{2014, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 31}]}]
```

to produce a series of simple numbers, because in version 9, this code produced this:

```
{22.5875, 22.6058, 22.6241, 22.6423, 22.6603, 22.6782, 22.6960, 
 22.7136, 22.7310, 22.7483, 22.7653, 22.7822, 22.7988, 22.8152, 
 22.8314, 22.8474, 22.8631, 22.8785, 22.8937, 22.9086, 22.9233, 
 22.9377, 22.9518, 22.9656, 22.9791, 22.9924, 23.0053, 23.0179, 
 23.0302, 23.0422, 23.0539}
```

So far, using version 10 I've managed to get as far as this:

```
Table[PlanetData["Jupiter", 
   EntityProperty["Planet", 
       "Declination", {"Date" -> DateObject[x]}]], 
   {x, DayRange[{2014, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 31}]}]
```

but it still produces a list of things which don't look or act like numbers:

[image: odd output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
Table[UnitConvert[
  PlanetData["Jupiter", 
   EntityProperty["Planet", 
    "Declination", {"Date" -> DateObject[x]}]], "Degrees"],
 {x, DayRange[{2014, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 31}]}]
```

Convert to numbers

```
QuantityMagnitude[%]
```

Comment: That's the one, thanks.